# expo doctor not supported, expo-cli doctor not fixing dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I am unable to run `npx expo doctor`

```
$ npx expo doctor

  $ expo doctor is not supported in the local CLI, please use expo-cli doctor instead
```

Tried out `expo-cli doctor --fix-dependencies` but it does not appear to have changed my `packages.json`.

```
$ expo-cli doctor --fix-dependencies
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~6.0.0
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.1
  (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
```

How do I fix the invalid packages issue?

Answer (score 7):

I upgraded to the latest Expo SDK 49 and encountered the same problem as you. The following commands worked for me.

```
npx expo-doctor
```

then

```
npx expo install --fix
```

Documentation is here
https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/

The commands below no longer worked for me.

1. npx expo doctor --fix-dependencies

   result in:

   $ expo doctor is not supported in the local CLI, please use npx
   expo-doctor instead
2. expo-cli doctor --fix-dependencies

   result in:

   'expo-cli doctor' is not supported for SDK 46 and higher. Use 'npx
   expo-doctor' instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. First make a copy of your current Expo project.
2. Delete all your node modules.
3. Install node modules with command

```
yarn
```

4. Then your issue of

```
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~6.0.0
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.1
  (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
```

can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

From your error messages, installing the latest version should fix your problems.

```
npm install @expo/config-plugins@latest
```

Then use the command below to check if your expo config-plugin has been updated to a version equal to or higher than 6.00, if it is still lower, retry the above command with the *--force* flag

```
npm ls @expo/config-plugins
```

Once that is done, run the command below to fix any other issue.

```
expo-cli doctor --fix-dependencies
```

Comment: `The global expo-cli package has been deprecated`